# Getting Ajax reponse as null in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form in that I am trying to do inline editing and adding using AJAX call.

Firstly I am displaying data in HTML table. And then if enter data into text boxes and click on add button record adding displaying data in HTML table. After I click edit button data showing in the textboxes fine.

But I am getting the ajax response as `null`.

I couldn't figure it out.

This is my AJAX code PHP file:

```
$(function() {
  $(".scrollingTable  tbody  a").click(function() {
    //debugger;
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var arr = link.split('=');
    var id = arr[1];
    //alert(id);
    $.ajax({
      url: "insertgr.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        cntid: id
      },
      success: function(datas) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(datas);
        $("#num").val(data.id);
        $("#namegr").val(data.vndr_cntname);
        $("#designation").val(data.designation);
        $("#mobilegr").val(data.vndr_cntmobile);
        $("#maildgr").val(data.vndr_cntmail);
      }
    });
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.txtcbt a').click(function() {
    debugger;
    var cntname, designation, mobile, email, vndrid, id, cid;
    cid = $("#num").val();
    cntname = $("#namegr").val();
    designation = $("#designation").val();
    mobile = $("#mobilegr").val();
    email = $("#maildgr").val();
    vndrid = "<?php echo $selectid; ?>";
    //alert(cid);
    if (cntname == "" || designation == "" || mobile == "" || email == "") {
      alert("fields should not be empty");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "insertgr.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          id: cid,
          name: cntname,
          dgnation: designation,
          mobileno: mobile,
          emailid: email,
          vid: vndrid
        },
        success: function(html) {
          var dat = $.parseJSON(html);
          alert(html);
          alert("it came to success");
          $("#num").val("");
          $('#namegr').val("");
          $('#designation').val("");
          $('#mobilegr').val("");
          $('#maildgr').val("");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is file AJAX is calling:

```
<?php
    require('Assests/connection/connection.php');
    error_reporting(0);
    $vcntlist = "";
    if (!empty($_POST['cntid'])) {
        $id = $_POST['cntid'];
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id`, `vndr_cntname`, `designation`, `vndr_cntmobile`, `vndr_cntmail`,`vndr_id` FROM `vndr_cntdtls`where id=$id");
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rowcount > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $vcntid = $row['id'];
            $cntname = $row['vndr_cntname'];
            $cntdesignation = $row['designation'];
            $cntmobile = $row['vndr_cntmobile'];
            $cntmail = $row['vndr_cntmail'];
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['dgnation']) &&
        !empty($_POST['mobileno']) && !empty($_POST['emailid']) &&
        !empty($_POST['vid'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $degination = $_POST['dgnation'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobileno'];
        $email = $_POST['emailid'];
        $vndrid = $_POST['vid'];
        if (empty($_POST['id'])) {
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `vndr_cntdtls`(`vndr_cntname`, `designation`, `vndr_cntmobile`, `vndr_cntmail`, `vndr_id`) VALUES ('$name','$degination','$mobile','$email',$vndrid)");
        } else {
            $update1 = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `vndr_cntdtls` SET `vndr_cntname`='$name',`designation`='$degination',`vndr_cntmobile`='$mobile',`vndr_cntmail`='$email' WHERE id=$id") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT  DISTINCT `id`, `vndr_cntname`, `designation`, `vndr_cntmobile`, `vndr_cntmail`,vc.vndr_id FROM `vndr_cntdtls` vc INNER JOIN vendors v ON vc.vndr_id=$vndrid") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rowcount > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $vcntid = $row['id'];
                $cntname = $row['vndr_cntname'];
                $cntdesignation = $row['designation'];
                $cntmobile = $row['vndr_cntmobile'];
                $cntmail = $row['vndr_cntmail'];
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

Comment: Didn't see that you had the full PHP file. For some reason, it didn't work out in my local PHP server or the formatter. Both crashed. Do you mind checking it out yourself? There's a huge issue with the code I believe... Trying to debug...

Comment: On an unrelated note you are interpolating PHP variables with the SQL query string, this can produce an unwanted attack vector within your application known as SQL Injection, to prevent this I would recommend using Prepared Statements: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: If you want html file too.What can I do to solve this problem.

Comment: @itsme I just tried to clear the clutter in the PHP, without modifying the code. Check and approve.

Comment: @itsme What do you get as output in the Console?

Comment: Alert message showing null

Comment: @itsme Not the alert message, but just trying to understand, what you get in the network tab when you first the AJAX call?

Comment: Just now i have checked network tab in respone section first the ajax call i am getting json string but when call second time it is giving response as null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161807/discussion-between-itsme-and-soolie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a lot of ways it is not working.

**First:**
You need to put a `application/json` in your php so it can be compatible with the browser you are using.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);
```

**Second:**
Why are you doing a while loop and assigning it into an unused variable?

You can simplify it by doing:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);
```

Unless it is multiple rows then:

```
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$rows = array();
if ($rowcount > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
 }
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);
```

**Third**
`null` values usually appears when a variable you are trying to use is not initialized. By having the error_reporting turned off it does not display the error.

`error_reporting(true);`

**Fourth**
Check also the logs for database error, I assume it has something to do with MySQL query not having to reach the `$row` initialization.

**Fifth**
I believe you need to have it fetched as associative array for it to be useful
`$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`